# map the specific record column to “sportsBallValueID” using "sportsBallValue" for display on dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I am trying to map the specific record column to `sportsBallValueID` using `sportsBallValue` for display on dropdowns. I am trying to display in `data.field`.

I have provided my code and json structure below:

```or-tag-here
private productEditor(container, data, that) {
        console.log("data--->" + data);

        this.rowDotMenuClick("true");
        if (data.model.archiveFlag == "Y") {
            console.log("data.model.programType--->" + data.model.programType);
            $('<label>' + data.model.programType + '</label>').appendTo(container);
        } else {
            console.log("data.field--->" + data.field);

            let input = $('<input name="' + data.field + '" class="k-input" />').appendTo(container);
            input.kendoComboBox(that.kendoComboBoxOptionProgramEditor).appendTo(container);
            $('.k-input-readonly').prop('readonly', true);
        }
    }


        "properties": {
            "Bug": [
                {
                    "level": null,
                    "propertyName": "Bug",
                    "delFlag": null,
                    "sportsBallID": 38,
                    "sportsBallValue": "BALL - BAX30049H",
                    "sportsBallValueID": 4218,
                    "propertyID": null,
                    "groupNo": null,
                    "targetDefaultsportsBallValueID": null,
                    "showNonNetworkGameInSL": null
                },
                {
                    "level": null,
                    "propertyName": "Bug",
                    "delFlag": null,
                    "sportsBallID": 38,
                    "sportsBallValue": "BALR - BAX30048H",
                    "sportsBallValueID": 4217,
                    "propertyID": null,
                    "groupNo": null,
                    "targetDefaultsportsBallValueID": null,
                    "showNonNetworkGameInSL": null
                },
                {
                    "level": null,
                    "propertyName": "Bug",
                    "delFlag": null,
                    "sportsBallID": 38,
                    "sportsBallValue": "BAUL - BAX30047H",
                    "sportsBallValueID": 4216,
                    "propertyID": null,
                    "groupNo": null,
                    "targetDefaultsportsBallValueID": null,
                    "showNonNetworkGameInSL": null
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Can you add a html code or create a pen in codepen.io ? Your question is so confusing :S

Comment: @ar kr, your question not clear and provided json values also invalid format, validate it here : https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @AnfathHifans hey I validated json....but not how to fix this error --->Error: Parse error on line 1:
"properties": { "Bug": [{   "l
------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'

Comment: how you are receiving the json value > where show the codes

Comment: @AnfathHifans hi...I am getting json values in data

Comment: update your question with full code,

Comment: @AnfathHifans hey my code is huge...shall I put that code alone in the link and give it to you?

Comment: @AnfathHifans hi pasting my whole code in the link https://jsfiddle.net/LvdkgfvL/