# TypeError: sportsRecord.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript, angular2-routing

updated answer1:

hi, I update the question with records and console

```
sportsRecord = {
        playerTigers:[
            {TigerNo: 237, TigerName: "Bird Bay Area", TigerkGroupNo: 1, isDefault: true, futureAccessDays: ""},
            {TigerkNo: 238, TigerName: "Bird California", TigerkGroupNo: 1, futureAccessDays: ""},
            {TigerkNo: 239, TigerName: "Bird Washington", TigerkGroupNo: 1, futureAccessDays: ""},
            {TigerNo: 240, TigerName: "Bird Philadelphia", TigerkGroupNo: 1, futureAccessDays: ""},
            {TigerNo: 241, TigerName: "TCN", TigerkGroupNo: 1, futureAccessDays: ""},
            {TigerNo: 242, TigerName: "Bird Chicago", TigerkGroupNo: 1, futureAccessDays: ""},
            {TigerNo: 243, TigerName: "Bird Boston", TigerkGroupNo: 1, futureAccessDays: ""},
            {TigerNo: 244, TigerName: "Bird Northwest", TigerkGroupNo: 1, futureAccessDays: ""}
        ]
}


console.log(sportsRecord instanceof Array); ---> false
console.log(sportsRecord.length) ---> undefined
```

- I am new to js.
- I am trying to iterate json structure.
- when I see isDefault: true, I need to show as a default name.
- I tried but right now I am getting an error .
- can you  tell me how to fix it.
- providing my relevant code below.
- code is very big so I am pasting in gist
  https://gist.github.com/niniyzni/5c19f385b35f9418086125799803efe7

```or-tag-here
TypeError: sportsRecord.find is not a function
    at birdLionUpdate.setTigers (bird-Lion-update.ts:981)
    at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (bird-Lion-update.ts:367)
```

```or-tag-here
   setTigers(sportsRecord: any) {

        let that = this;
        let tempObj = {};
        //tempObj['TigerNo'] = 237;
        //tempObj['Lion'] = getDefault(playermoons).Lion

       // tempObj['TigerNo'] = this.getDefault(sportsRecord).TigerNo;
        let defauktTigerNOsportsRecord =  sportsRecord.find((elem) => { return elem.isDefault; });




        tempObj['TigerNo'] = sportsRecord.playerTigers[0].TigerNo;
        tempObj['TigerName'] = 'Nail Sports Bay Area';
        // tempObj['TigerNo'] = sportsRecord.selectedTigerNo;
        // tempObj['TigerName'] = sportsRecord.selectedTigerName;
        this.TigerTempArray = [];
        this.TigerTempArray.push(tempObj);
        let TigerssportsRecord = sportsRecord.playerTigers;
        let TigerssportsRecordList = this.TigerTempArray;
        let selectedTiger = TigerssportsRecord.find(elem => elem.TigerNo == 237);
        this.playerLionUpdateVal.TigerNo = 237;
        // let selectedTiger = TigerssportsRecord.find(elem => elem.TigerNo == sportsRecord.selectedTigerNo);
        // this.LionCreateVal.TigerNo = sportsRecord.selectedTigerNo;
        this.selectedTigerArr = selectedTiger;
        this.TigerCarousel.setTigersportsRecord(TigerssportsRecord, TigerssportsRecordList, 237);
        //this.TigerCarousel.setTigersportsRecord(TigerssportsRecord, TigerssportsRecordList, sportsRecord.selectedTigerNo);
        $("#TigerCarouselLabel .TigerHint").css("display", "none");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#unSelectedTigersLogoBox1 .currentNwLogo").bind("click", function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                that.singleSelection(sportsRecord, e);
            });
        }, 100);
    }T
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems sportsRecord is empty or it does not have any elements in it.

You can add a check as

```
if(sportsRecord && sportsRecord.length > 0){
 let defauktTigerNOsportsRecord =  sportsRecord.playerTigers.find((elem) => { return elem.isDefault; });
}
```

Comment: hey I get value inside sportsRecord is there any other problem or is there any other way to get the TigerNo for isDefault

Comment: is it an object or array

Comment: post your data what you see

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I update the question with records and console......can you tell me how to proceed

Comment: check the updated answwer because playerTigers is the array inside sportsRecord

Comment: hey thanks so much...can you help me with this one too ---> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49960917/map-the-specific-record-column-to-sportsballvalueid-using-sportsballvalue-fo?noredirect=1#comment86951643_49960917

Answer (score 1):

Either sportsRecord is not coming in as an Array, or your browser version does not have support for the Array.find() api. If you suspect this, check out the compatibility table at the bottom of the mozilla documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

BTW MDN is an amazing resource when learning JS and when you're advanced.

To double check sportsRecord is an array, try logging to the console right before that line, like so:

```
console.log(sportsRecord instanceof Array);
let defauktTigerNOsportsRecord =  sportsRecord.find((elem) => { return elem.isDefault; });
...
```